# How to truncate a number

Tags: html, perl, numbers, decimal, truncate

I should  display numbers to a table. But I need The number has only two characters after a comma. How to do it correctly.

```
            $score =  $schet;
%>
            <tr class="ten" >
                <td class="six" > <%= $schet %></td>
                <td> <%= $d->start %></td>
                <td> <%= $d->end   %></td>
            </tr>
<%
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf):

```
my $number_with_two_decimal_places = sprintf '%.2f', $float;
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a result whot I need  <%= sprintf( "%.02f", $d->overall_start_debet   ) %>